# How to find the most meaningful words in the text with using word2vec?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

So, for instance, I'm typing, as an input, some sentence with some semantic meaning and, as an output, I get some list of closest (in cosine distance) words (mostly single words).

But I want to understand which cluster my sentence belongs to and compute how far is located each word from it. And eliminate non-meaningful words from sentence.

For example:

"I want to buy a pizza";

"pizza": 0.99123

"buy": 0.7834

"want": 0.1443

How such requirement can be achieved out of the box, without any C coding?

Maybe I need to compute cosine distance equation for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need topic modeling instead of word2vec. Word2vec is used to capture local information, it is not a good idea to use it directly to classify or clustering words or sentences.

One other aspect can be stop word removal since you are mentioning about non-meaningful words. By the way, they are not non-meaningful, they are actually not aligned with any topic. So, you are thinking them as non-meaningful.

I believe you should use LDA topic modeling approach and you don't need to implement anything since there are many implementation out there for LDA.